# Remove string after second "-"

Tags: swift

I currently have a string that's based on news headlines and at the end there is a - with the source which I do not want.
Example: "Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks - TheStreet.com"

Currently to get rid of it I am using:

```
if let range = str.range(of: "-"){
      str.removeSubrange(range.lowerBound..<str.endIndex)}
```

However I have run into a problem where if there are 2 "-"'s the entire string after the first one will get cut off.

For example 
"Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks - TheStreet.com" will become "Stock"

My question is how can I make it so only the ending - and after will be removed in the substring?

Comment: Consider `lastIndex`. Or reverse the string, do what you are doing, and reverse the result.

Comment: Consider using String.components(separatedBy:)

Comment: How should the code behave if there are hyphens/dashes in the source part of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code:

```
extension String {
    mutating func removeFromLast(_ ch: Character) {
        if let index = lastIndex(of: ch) {
            removeSubrange(index..<endIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

```
var s = "Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks - TheStreet.com"
s.removeFromLast("-")
print(s)
// "Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use collection's method `lastIndex` method to find out the last occurrence of the dash character:

```
var str =  "Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks - TheStreet.com"

if let index = str.lastIndex(where: {$0 == "-"}) {
    str.removeSubrange(index...)
}

print(str) // "Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks "
```

You can also use `range(of: String)` setting `.backwards` option:

```
if let range = str.range(of: " - ", options: .backwards) {
    str.removeSubrange(range.lowerBound...)  
}

print(str)   // "Stock - Lower as Wall Street Awaits Fed's Decision on Rates, FedEx Sinks"
```